# Different combinations of summands of N

Tags: c++, recursion

The programme should to write, how many different combinations of natural summands of N. All of summands doesn't bigger, then K (N,K<=120).
My programme is consist of recursion only:

```
int  F (int x,int s)  // s- total number, which is necessary to lay down the terms of
{
if (s == 0) // when total number == 0
    {
        ans++;   
        return 0;
    }
for (int i=x;i<=min(k,s);i++) // x - previous term
    F(i,s-i);           // we add a new summand -> subtract that number from the amount
}
```

And main part:

```
int main ()
{
 cin >> n>> k;
 F(1,n);
 cout << ans;
}
```

So, can you help me to do my program faster?

Comment: You have some errors in your code, such as ` ans` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: @ctrl-shift-esc All of variables are declared after "using namespce std;"... If you want, I can to edit my code, and I'll write it.

Comment: @user3623421 `F` doesn't return anything unless `n` is 0. Since the return type of `F` is not void, that has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user2079303 It is not necessary.

Comment: You should put a little more effort in writing down your question if you're expecting or hoping to get good answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can add memoization. There is no need to compute F for fixed x and s more than once.
It requires slightly changing your code(to make F actually return computed value instead of incerementing ans) and adding an array to hold already calculated values.

Answer (score 0):

this was a fun exersize;

```
int F (int x,int s)
{
    static map< int, map< int, int > > table;

    if( (x==s) || (s==0) ) return 1;
    if( x > s ) return 0;

    auto itr1 = table.find(x);
    if( itr1 != table.end() )
    {
        auto& sub = itr1->second;
        auto itr2 = sub.find(s);
        if( itr2 != sub.end() )
        {
            return itr2->second;
        }
    }

    int ans=1;
    for ( int i=x; i<s; ++i )
        ans += F(i,s-i);

    table[x][s]=ans;
    return ans;
}
```